# UserForm being initialized unexpectedly in the middle of a button_click() sub

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a basic UserForm which allows the user to add values to a list in a range. In the middle of a button_click() private sub, the userform "crashes" and goes to the the Private Sub UserForm_Initialize().

The error occurs in the following loop:

```
i = 0

For Each Cell In Range("GHKDelegates")
    Cell.Value = StrArray(i) 'this is where the error occurs
    If Str = "" Then
        Str = StrArray(i)
        i = i + 1
    Else
        Str = Str & vbCrLf & StrArray(1, i)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next Cell
```

No error message is shown, hence the confusion as to why  this is happening.

Comment: Does your range contain empty cells ?

Comment: What are the dimensions of `StrArray`? In your code it is treated as 1-D `StrArray(i)` and 2-D `StrArray(1, i)`.